# No translation for "people chatting"

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, localization

The new people chatting box has no string to translate for localized sites:

> [image]

The old one string (`9cb971b40cb463eb499299c67c3a06cd`) has Capitalized Words.

Comment: I wonder why this is constantly an issue. Can’t the Stack Exchange team incorporate always adding a Transifex string as part of the process of changing parts of the site?

Comment: Oh... We lower-cased it. Also "Visit [c]hat". Both should appear once strings are refreshed.

Comment: Should be available now, [yeah?](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=3386310bc2a7c5fe36e3ec04d604ef1f)

Comment: @Shog9 translated now. Will wait for rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed and translated now:

> [image]