# Is there a way to prevent appearance of untranslatable strings in SE code base?

Tags: feature-request, localization

Being a part of "Stack Overflow in Russian" translation team I'm wondering why do some new strings not able to translate due to the lack in translation database?

As far as I know for the string surrounding it with the function like `tr("english string that needs to be translated")` is enough to make it translatable (i.e. automatically placed as a source string into Transifex database). Hence, it should be not too hard to detect such strings on code review stage or even by auto-check before merging new commit into working branch.

Is there a way to prevent appearance of untranslatable strings (which should be translatable for localized sites) in SE code base?

Comment: Think it's something for the developers to discuss internally, doubt we can/should have active part in it. (Of course, when such string appear, it's fine to report the text that can't be translated. :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard since I'm not fluent in English as I would like and Russian is more convenient for me, I can't agree with you. If open discussion will help to improve the internal localization process I think it's useful to be here. Less untranslatable strings - less bug reports about them :)

Comment: Related: [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324302/no-translation-for-people-chatting#comment1059601_324302) from two and half months ago.

Comment: @Rob nope. My question is about minimizing untranslatable string in site's engine, suggested by you is about translation (for translatable strings) before rolling out the actual build.

Comment: What are you really asking here? You've tagged this as both [tag:discussion] and [tag:support] neither of which seem appropriate. As a [tag:support] question your question would be read as something like "As a user of this site, is there any way for me to change the source code process or force the developers to do X?" The obvious answer to that is "No". It's so obvious that it seems nonsensical to ask as a [tag:support] question.

Comment: As a [tag:discussion], this question would be something like "Given the entire development process that SE uses, is it possible to establish a part of the process such that no untranslatable strings are permitted in the code?" This, again, seems very strange to be asking, because it really is asking users here to speculate on SE's development process and what changes might be able to be made to it. It's really not a productive discussion to have here without substantially more visibility into SE's development process.

Comment: On the other hand, something similar to this as a [tag:feature-request] asking SE to establish, as a part of the development process, checks to ensure that the code (or at least new code) doesn't have strings which are untranslatable. Such a feature request would actually be useful.