# Localization of magic link MCVE is broken

Tags: bug, comments, localization, magic-links, international-sites

We saw that there was a wording change on how to handle MCVE. Since this change went live, we saw that the wording on international sites is broken.

Since we didn't have a full discussion about this change on international sites, and since we don't want to show magic links in the wrong language, can we get the default wording in every language, until we come out with a new wording on every language?

[image]

Comment: [Announcement of change on Meta Stack Overflow (English)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark?cb=1)

Comment: I was looking for that post here.. and couldn't find it.. thanks a lot @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog

Comment: the links point to the correct page.. but now the link is in english.. and also we didn't reword the page, so it's still mcve for us... @Rob

Comment: Missing localization overall seems to be a problem. See also [is there a way to prevent appearance of untranslatable strings in SE code base](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327742/332043)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has all been a bit of a...

Well, in English we refer to it with a phrase that begins with "cluster". Let's call it a "[cluster headache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_headache)".

Anyway... The string "reproducible" should now appear only a few times in the entire codebase. You may find them with a search query like this: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29reproducible ([es](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29reproducible), [pt](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29reproducible), [ja](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29reproducible))- the second result there is the important one, provide a translation for that and it should take care of the issue.

I apologize for the inconvenience; this isn't something that should happen often, but... It still does.

Comment: Or those things that rhyme with those creatures... ... [feathers, long beak, go quack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZ66wHRhe2U)... oh yes, *cats*. Or that patron saint of things that go oops in the night... Murphy...

Comment: Half of the world is looking at you guys.. with laser pointers ;)...